# jQuery to select specific selects that have "selected" in the option

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form with multiple selects that is dynamically pre-populated with options.

I'd like to highlight (change background color) for only selects that have "selected" in the option list.

Form:

```
<form name="MyForm" method="POST" action="/myaction">
    <select>
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="1">111</option>
        <option value="2" selected>222</option>
        <option value="3">333</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="1">A1</option>
        <option value="2">B2</option>
        <option value="3">C3</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="A" selected>AAA</option>
        <option value="B">BBB</option>
        <option value="C">CCC</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

My current jQuery highlights ALL of the selects, not only the ones that have "selected" within options. In the above example only first and last selects should have been highlighted...

```
$('#MyForm').find('select > option:selected').parent().css('background-color', 'rgba(216,255,1,0.15)');
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you are looking for the attribute `selected`:

```js
$('[name=MyForm] [selected]').parent().css('background-color', 'rgba(216,255,1,0.15)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="MyForm" method="POST" action="/myaction">
    <select>
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="1">111</option>
        <option value="2" selected>222</option>
        <option value="3">333</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="1">A1</option>
        <option value="2">B2</option>
        <option value="3">C3</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="A" selected>AAA</option>
        <option value="B">BBB</option>
        <option value="C">CCC</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Form element with `name="MyForm"` but using 'MyForm' in  jquery  as a id selector `$('#MyForm'). Either assign`id="MyForm"` to your form tag or use the below jquery

```
$('[name="MyForm"]').find('select > option:selected').parent().css('background-color', 'rgba(216,255,1,0.15)');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward.
Replace `option:selected` with `option[selected]` and add the attribute `id="MyForm"` to the form.

You can see the code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/xwz2tLLz/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedItems= $('[name="MyForm"]').find('select > option:selected');    
selectedItems.each(function(obj,ind){    
     $(obj).parent().css('background-color', 'rgba(216,255,1,0.15)');
});
```